# showing a bootstrap tab using a button's onClick event

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am having trouble activating/showing a bootstrap tab with the onClick event of a bootstrap button (updated code and additional declarations included).

Here are the tab definitions:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#Tab1">Tab1</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#Tab2">Tab2</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the content declaration for tab2:

```
<div id="Tab2" class="tab-pane fade show">
  <div>
     <br/>
     <br/>
     <br/>
     <p>
        This is tab2
     </p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the button code:

```
<tr>
  <td style="width: 33%">database</td>
  <td style="width: 33%">Object</td>
  <td style="width: 33%"><button class="btn btn-success" name="e1" onClick="showTab()">Inspect</button></td>
</td>
</tr>
```

and here is the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function showTab() {
   $('Tab2').tab('show');
}
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers,
Gaetano.

Comment: you need to remove the last `)` in the script code so it will be like that  `<script type="text/javascript">function showTab() {
  ('#Tab2').tab('show');
  };
</script>`

Comment: and for `#Tab2` it is not in your html code so you need to declare it if you are not.

Answer (score 0):

- There is an additional `);` at the end of the function.
- The jQuery Selector is not used (`$` or `jQuery`).

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function showTab() {
     $('#Tab2').tab('show');
    }
  </script>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This script syntax works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function showTab() {
$('.nav-tabs a[href="#Tab2"]').tab('show');
  }
</script>
```

there is still value in understanding why the original doesn't work, for my education, as I am a total novice to Javascript, I only use snippets here and there as needed.